# Multiple CSS Pseudo Classes

Tags: css, syntax

What is the proper CSS syntax for applying multiple pseudo classes to a selector.  I'd like to insert "," after each item in a list except the last one.  I am using the following css:

```
ul.phone_numbers li:after {
    content: ",";
}

ul.phone_numbers li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

This works fine on FF3, Chrome and Safari 3.  IE7 doesn't work because it doesn't support :after (as expected).  In IE 8 this renders with a comma after each li including the last one.  Is this a problem with IE8 or is my syntax incorrect?  It's ok if it doesn't work in IE8 but I would like to know what the proper syntax is.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`:last-child` is a pseudo-class, whereas `:after` (or `::after` in  CSS3) is a pseudo-element.

To quote [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes):

> Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere in selectors while pseudo-elements may only be appended after the last simple selector of the selector.

This means your syntax is correct according to CSS2.1 and [CSS3 as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax), i.e. IE8 still sucks ;)

Comment: Can I write element:hover:disable {} multiple pseudo-classes ? Is it good practice ?

Comment: I used that to make this happen, li:first-child:before { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```
ul.phone_numbers li + li:before {
   content: ",";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem nesting pseudo class selectors as long as the rules applied match the particular element in the DOM-tree . 
I want to echo the possibilities of styling with pseudo class selectors from [w3 website](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors) . 
That means you can also do stuff like :

```
.ElClass > div:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    /*your css styles here ... */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this by having a another tag inside the `<li/>` and apply the `:after` to that instead. That way you would be applying the `:last-child` and `:after` to different elements:

```css
ul.phone_numbers li > span:after {
    content: ",";
}

ul.phone_numbers li:last-child > span:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't support last-child :( They're focused on sorting out CSS 2.1 support it looks like. Why microsoft haven't adopted Gecko or Webkit yet I don't know.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#pseudoclasses

Comment: Thanks for the info and explanation.  Is my syntax correct?  Just in case IE9 supports last-child.

Comment: Yeah the syntax is fine, as the other guys have said :)