# Combining :hover and :nth-child(n4+4)?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm stuck and can't figure out a fix to my current problem and was hoping to get some help and/or direction.

I was wondering if there is a way to combine the :hover and :nth-child(4n+4) pseudo classes. If you visit [my sandbox page](http://inexxus.com/dev/ttt/template/mytiks.php) there is an un-ordered list (the deal polaroids) where I have every 4th list item display a zero margin. The problem is that the :hover adds a 10px padding that breaks the flow on every 4th list item. I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the flicker that is caused by hovering over those list items. I tried combining things to no avail and using "!important" (which I try and avoid). Can anyone help? I that I'm overlooking something and a second pair of eyes would help.

here is the CSS/HTML:

CSS:

```css
ul#myTiks li {
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 35px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    color: #333;
}

ul#myTiks li:hover {
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url(../img/dwt/white_bgd_30.png);
    margin: -10px 25px 25px -10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

ul#myTiks li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
<div class="polaroid">
            <div class="title">Title Of Deal</div>
            <div class="category">Deal Category</div>
            <div class="tik"><a href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="img"><img src="../img/dwt/myTik_placeholder_img.png" width="197" height="197"></div>
            <div class="soc" style="display:none;">
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/dwt/tweet_btn_x20h.png" width="55" height="20"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/dwt/fb_like_btn_x20h.png" width="46" height="20"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/dwt/pin_btn_x20h.png" width="55" height="20"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Related? Check accepted answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493232/multiple-css-pseudo-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your right margin to `-10px`, no need for important:

```css
ul#myTiks li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Ha, no worries, I doubt very much you are retarded, you've probably just been staring at it for too long :)