# define pseudo class and pseudo element in same element

Tags: css, hover

My question is really simple, just what i am trying to do is `:hover`, `:after` and `:before` , i want hover anf after to embed in same element, check out my css code:-

```css
#sidebar .widget li a:before:hover, #sidebar .widget li a.active:before { 
    background-position: 65% 65.7%;
}
```

Here the element have an icon in `:before` which i cnt remove or modify, and also i want to have an hover effect on it...

Any solution for this, my console doesn't show the hovering effect?

Comment: Just to be clear, `:hover` is not a [pseudo _element_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), it's a [pseudo _class_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). Also, would you mind to provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  If you're able to show us a working example we could probably be of more help.

However, in theory there's nothing wrong with what you're attempting to do (although not all browsers will like it: particularly IE8 and below).

The important thing to understand here is that `:hover` is a pseudo-*class*, whereas `:before` is a pseudo-*element*.

Here's a quick excerpt from [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes) (with thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493291/607004) previously on Stack Overflow):

> Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere in selectors while pseudo-elements
>   may only be appended after the last simple selector of the selector.

The mistake you're making is in your syntax: the order that you're appending them.

Try this instead:

```
#sidebar .widget li a:hover:before,
#sidebar .widget li a.active:before { 
    background-position: 65% 65.7%;
}
```

That should do as you wish.  However this isn't going to give you great cross-browser coverage, it's not something that all browsers support of have implemented.

A better approach would be to:

- reset the `:before` element to nothing (overwrite the styles you can't access);
- use a non-repeated background image on the anchor instead (to display the image), and padding-left to give the indentation;
- You can then switch the background-image in whatever fashion you see fit using `:hover` on the anchor in your CSS.

This will give you far better cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Hi @SaurabhLP that's great, glad that we were able to help!  If your question is answered now, please do ensure that you mark the correct answer (there's a tick icon alongside each answer - the relevant one just needs ticking).  This ensures that people coming to the site in the future with a similar problem will be able to easily find the relevant answer too.