# Two css pseudo classes

Tags: html, css

I want to use :after on :target element to select element in css. I tried this code but it isn't work.

```
.myclass a:target:after{}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/57RPT/1/

Comment: I fixed it, thnx to all :)

Comment: <li class="myclass">       
    <a  href="#tab2"><strong>Cars</strong>
        </a>
</li> i deleted <strong> and it fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`:target` is a pseudo-class

`:after` is a pseudo-element.

[W3.org - link - state that:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes):

> Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere in selectors while pseudo-elements may only be appended after the last simple selector of the selector.

[This question is basically a duplicate, go here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493291/1045794)

Comment: according the link the syntax is correct? But it doesn't work to me. So the problem is in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a `span:target::after { }`