# Combine :first-of-type and :after

Tags: css

Is it possible to combine :first-of-type and :after on the same class? 
For example:

```css
.feature.feature--featured:first-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #4a90e2;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature feature--featured feature-1 boxed boxed--border bg--white">
    <h5>This is a title</h5>
    <p>
      21 July, 2019
    </p>
    <a href="#">
                                            Read Story
                                        </a>
    <span class="label">New</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature feature--featured feature-1 boxed boxed--border bg--white">
    <h5>This is a title</h5>
    <p>
      21 July, 2019
    </p>
    <a href="#">
                                            Read Story
                                        </a>
    <span class="label">New</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature feature--featured feature-1 boxed boxed--border bg--white">
    <h5>This is a title</h5>
    <p>
      21 July, 2019
    </p>
    <a href="#">
                                            Read Story
                                        </a>
    <span class="label">New</span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Can't get it working. Thanks!

Comment: show your HTML .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple CSS Pseudo Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493232/multiple-css-pseudo-classes)

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: Don't know about you, but I clicked on run code snippet and I see the blue line in the bottom.

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for your help. I only want the after element on the first object. Now every col-md-4 has the blue bottom visual.

Comment: then you should put `first of type` on `col-md-4`

Comment: *Now every col-md-4 has the blue bottom visual* --> there is only one col in the code you shared. Share a full and complete code to better show your issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif updated it with the whole row.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for your help. But it's a little bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation why your code fails

What you may not be aware of and commenters as well as the other answer missed to point out, is that `:first-of-type` works in the **context of sibling elements** and not in the context of the whole HTML document as you may have thought.

> [MDN `:first-of-type` spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)
>
> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

Your `.feature.feature--featured` are **all first of its type** in their respective sibling context. They're all the first (and only) child within their parent element. Hence they all have the `:after` pseudo element attached to them. You only see one of these *afters* because they're all absolutely positioned and at the same position so they're rendered on top of each other. But there are still multitude of them.

So **the correct solution** is that you need to do `:first-of-type` on `.col-md-4` because they're siblings within their parent element so the pseudo element will only be related to the child feature element of the first one (see [@Mr Lister's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58706235/75642) for the code).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your explanation. This was something I really didn't knew. Wonderfull!

Comment: I did fail to point out that `:first-of-type` is really a variant of `:first-child`, yes. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, if you want only the first div with `col-md-4` to be targeted, put the `first-of-type` qualifier on the `.col-md-4` class rather than the `.feature.feature--featured` class. That is all.

```css
.col-md-4:first-of-type .feature.feature--featured::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #4a90e2;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature feature--featured feature-1 boxed boxed--border bg--white">
    <h5>This is a title</h5>
    <p>
      21 July, 2019
    </p>
    <a href="#">
                                            Read Story
                                        </a>
    <span class="label">New</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature feature--featured feature-1 boxed boxed--border bg--white">
    <h5>This is a title</h5>
    <p>
      21 July, 2019
    </p>
    <a href="#">
                                            Read Story
                                        </a>
    <span class="label">New</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature feature--featured feature-1 boxed boxed--border bg--white">
    <h5>This is a title</h5>
    <p>
      21 July, 2019
    </p>
    <a href="#">
                                            Read Story
                                        </a>
    <span class="label">New</span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Really appreciated.